# how to save utf-8 characters from python to mySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I use python on a server to communicate with mySQL.  If a string with non-ascii characters is given to python to convey into a mySQL table field I get this error from the server.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 251-256: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I pass through utf-8 data.  I do have the comment:

```
"# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-"
```

...included in the python main code page, as well as all the code pages.

Strangely enough I am able to fetch data from mySQL which contains UTF-8 characters and it transfers well down to JavaScript.

The line of code which attempts to transfer the data is as follows:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO clientMail (clientID,coID,MessageDate,TypeSent,Comments,FName)
        VALUES(%s, %s, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ''' % (clientID,companyID,currentDate,TypeSent,emailMessage,company_Name)
print "===>>>>>>>>>>>>>",sql
```

The UTF-8 characters occur in the Comments field

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 5):

A very quick fix should be to ensure that your string is Unicode to start with:

```
sql = u"INSERT..."
```

ie prefix the string with a `u`.

However, you should **not** be using string formatting to interpolate values into SQL statements. You should rely on the MySQL adapter to do that for you, to ensure that you are protected against SQL injection:

```
sql = u"INSERT... VALUES (%s, %s..)"
cursor.execute(sql, (clientID, companyID...,))
```

Comment: I get this result using your advice...    "c.execute(sql, clientID,companyID,currentDate,TypeSent,emailMessage,company_Name)
TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)"   but I only gave it 6 arguments and 6 fields defined...

Comment: Apologies, the values should be in a single tuple. Changed.

Comment: How does the MySQL adapter prevent SQL injections?  I'm new to this!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say that someone here did help, but I was not able to get it going, no matter how hard I tried...  Nevertheless, thank you all for trying.  I learned something from all anyway.

The way to get this admittedly difficult problem solved is as follows:
The connection parameters must include the following items

```
... charset="utf8", use_unicode=True"
```

Without these nothing you do will work, as I have concluded.  But I am a novice, so don't take me too seriously.

Nevertheless, thank you all so much for pitching in.... You guys rock.

Dennis

Answer (score -1):

Your data ought to be Unicode and string formatting (%s) is forcing it to string type using default encoding (ASCII).

Use .encode('utf-8') on your Unicode strings and you'll be all set.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to implement this function?  How do I get rid of the %s and replace it with .encode()...???  Sorry, I'm new to all this...

Comment: The encoding in which MySQL returns data to the client will depend on the current value of the [`character_set_results`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_results) session variable: one usually has to specify the desired character set on connecting to MySQL, or using the `SET NAMES` command thereafter (I don't know whether the Python connector in use here handles this for you..?).

Comment: This is not quite true: `u'%s' % 'a'` returns unicode. -1 for not mentioning that he should not use string formatting to generate a SQL expression.

Comment: @Dkean : you use encode on your unicode data and you keep the %s.  (All the unicode strings between the brackets after the %!)

Comment: @Thomas  Here is what I get.  The two fields are the only ones in need of utf-8:
    VALUES(%s, %s, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ''' % (clientID,companyID,currentDate,TypeSent,emailMessage.encode('utf-8'),company_Name.encode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 520: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @eggyal  Hi, how are you doing...   Here is how I connect to mySQL:             db = MySQLdb.connect(host = Quirc.SQL_server, user = Quirc.SQL_user, passwd = Quirc.SQL_password, db="ppp")